# CTP5: self-reference issue?

Tags: entity-framework-ctp5

there is a simple model:

```
public class Node
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }
}
```

the following map code will throw an exception:

```
public class NodeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().HasOptional(n => n.Parent).WithMany().IsIndependent().Map(m => m.MapKey(p => p.Id, "ParentId"));

    }
}
```

Could it be that it is not capable of self-reference custom foreign key name do it?

Comment: What is CTP5? Linq2Entities is only a guess...

Comment: What was the exception that was thrown?

Answer (score 1):

I do the same, but I don't rely on EF getting the keys correct and I do it myself. So my `Node` class looks like the following:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}

    public virutal Node Parent {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Node> Children {get;set;}
}
```

And then the ModelBuilder is setup as follows:

```
builder.Entity<Node>().HasKey(x => x.Id);

builder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.Parent)
        .WithMany(c => c.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentId);

builder.Entity<Node>().ToTable("Node");
```